# Unknown filesystem type on a MacOS

Tags: partitioning, mount, mac, macosx

I'm trying to mount a MacOS filesystem `/dev/sda2` from a Linux machine, but trying to mount it fails with

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock
```

when issuing

```
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda2 /mountpoint
```

I have tried installing `hfsprogs` with

```
sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
```

and specifying `-t hfsplus` but it fails in the same way. Neither `blkid /dev/sda2` nor `fdisk -l /dev/sda` are able to tell me anything about the filesystem on the partition.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

On recent MacOS versions (10.13 High Sierra and up, September 2017), the filesystem in use is not HFS+ but APFS. This filesystem is not documented and Linux is not currently able to mount it. There is only an experimental FUSE driver to mount it in read-only (haven't tried it yet): https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse